# Inverse search on AUCTeX opens file in new Emacs window instead of main Emacs window - how to avoid that?

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, evince

I am using Emacs+auctex+evince on Debian. Suppose I have a latex document `main.tex` which includes`sections/sec1.tex`. When compiling with `C-c C-a` from within `main.tex` and using backwards search in Section 1, Emacs opens `sections/sec1.tex` within a new Emacs window (Ew) (but within the same window in the sense of the window manager, aka frame in Emacs speak, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame). That is, the Ew showing `main.tex` is halved in size, a new Ew is created in the spare space, and I am seeing both `main.tex` and `sec1.tex`.

I would like to avoid that, instead having the file opened in the Ew that showed `main.tex` before.

I am using Emacs on Debian stable:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.5)
 of 2019-09-22, modified by Debian
```

The undesired behaviour is shown with a virgin configuration, hence does not seem to be caused by any customization I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment, the answer

```
(setq same-window-regexps '("\\.tex$"))
```

has the unintended consequence of breaking the AucTeX commands `C-c C-l` and `` C-c C-` `` .  One way to fix this is to restrict the new value of `same-window-regexps` to TeX-mode buffers, i.e. replace the above line with

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
           '(lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'same-window-regexps) '("\\.tex$"))))
```

However, this restricts it as a solution to the original problem so that it only works when Emacs is currently viewing *some* TeX file; if the current buffer is a different mode, then reverse-search opens in a separate Emacs-window.

A different solution that seems to work in all cases is to keep the original global `(setq same-window-regexps '("\\.tex$"))`, but trick `C-c C-l` and `` C-c C-` ``  into telling `TeX-pop-to-buffer` to always open in another window:

```
(defun TeX-force-pop-to-buffer-other-window (orig-fun buffer &optional other-window norecord)
  (funcall orig-fun buffer t norecord))
(defun TeX-force-pop-in-other-window (orig-fun &rest rest)
  "Don't depend on `pop-to-buffer' using a different window."
  (advice-add 'TeX-pop-to-buffer :around 'TeX-force-pop-to-buffer-other-window)
  (apply orig-fun rest)
  (advice-remove 'TeX-pop-to-buffer 'TeX-force-pop-to-buffer-other-window))  
(advice-add 'TeX-help-error :around 'TeX-force-pop-in-other-window)
(advice-add 'TeX-recenter-output-buffer :around 'TeX-force-pop-in-other-window)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this question, provided by Mike Shulman, is to use

```
(setq same-window-regexps '("\\.tex$"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that this solution has the unintended consequence of breaking the AucTeX commands `C-c C-l` and ``C-c C-` ``, which expect `pop-to-buffer` to always choose a different window: they first pop to the buffer they want to display and then pop *back* to the original window, assuming that this will leave the new buffer displayed in a separate window.  I will post a solution to this as a separate answer.